# contenedor que no sobrepase el 100% de alto

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quiero lograr que mi pagina se mantenga siempre ocupando el 100% ancho y 100% alto.  El problema lo tengo al hacer uso de las unidades vh y la clase "h-100" de BootStrap 4.

Cuando al row que tiene el contenido le digo "h-100" este me empuja el row que contiene el pie de pagina, generandome el scroll vertical.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-info" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="row bg-danger">
      <div class="col-12">HEADER</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bg-success h-100">
      <div class="col">
        CONTENIDO
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12">
        PIE DE PAGINA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en que tienes un `div class=container-fluid` que ocupa todo el alto de la pantalla y, en su interior, tienes otros tres:
`div class=row bg-danger` - Coge el alto automático según su contenido.
`div class=row bg-success h-100` - Coge el 100% del alto del padre.
`div class=row bg-warning` - Coge el alto automático según su contenido.

Siendo más específicos, al 100% del padre le sumas el alto de la cabecera y el pie y, por lo tanto, la suma es superior a 100vh y se crea el scroll.

Si no me equivoco, las clases de Boostrap que se refieren a `height` están limitadas a 0%, 25%, 50%, 75% y 100%, por lo que tendrás que jugar con las clases y porcentajes para conseguir lo que quieres:

Como dato: No es recomendable usar estilos en línea, lo ideal es crear clases para el elemento a editar y hacerlo a través de un `css` externo. (Yo he usado las mismas clases que tenías, pero sería más recomendable hacerlo como phpMyGuel)

```css
.container-fluid.bg-info {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row.bg-danger, .row.bg-warning {
  height: 10%
}

.row.bg-success {
  height: 80%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-info">
    <div class="row bg-danger">
      <div class="col-12">HEADER</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bg-success">
      <div class="col">
        CONTENIDO
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12">
        PIE DE PAGINA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
#cabecera {
  height: 30px;
}

#contenido {
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}

#pie {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="description" content="Demo project">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid bg-info" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div id="cabecera" class="row bg-danger">
      <div class="col-12">HEADER</div>
    </div>

    <div id="contenido" class="row bg-success">
      <div class="col">
        CONTENIDO
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="pie" class="row bg-warning">
      <div class="col-12">
        PIE DE PAGINA
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

El problema lo tienes en que los `vh` hacen referencia a la  altura del dispositivo. Si el `.container-fluid` lo tienes a `height: 100vh` y luego al contenedor del contenido le estás dando la clase `h-100` lo que estás haciendo es que el `.container-fluid` mida: **altura del header + altura del disposivo + altura del footer**.

Para solucionarlo, podrías darle un tamaño fijo a los contenedores del **header** y del **pie** y luego el contenido hacer que tenga de altura el 100% de la altura de su padre (que es el `.container-fluid` con altura `100vh`) y a eso restarle la suma de las alturas del contenedor del header y del contenedor del píe.

Para hacer eso la función `calc()` de **CSS** te viene al pelo.