# ¿Cómo ajusto bootstrap a la pantalla?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Estoy realizando un proyecto con bootstrap, usando html, css y php. El caso es que no entiendo por qué no se ajusta a la pantalla, os adjunto una captura:
[image: La zona roja es la parte de la pantalla que no se ajusta.]

La zona roja es la parte que queda en blanco, justo debajo ya aparecería la barra de Windows. Pongo el código que tengo:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- Cabecera -->

<head>  
    <?php
    include('head.php');
    ?>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<!-- Cuerpo -->

<body>

    <!-- Cabecera -->
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Gestión de proyectos I.E.S. Jacarandá</h1>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Filas -->
    <div class="container fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <img src="img/jacalogo.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <?php
                    include("formAcceso.php");
                ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Pie -->
    <?php
        include("pie.php");
    ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

No sé si es problema de haber dividido en bloques la web, porque está ideado así: cabecera es una fila, cuerpo es una fila de dos columnas y el pie igual. Dependiendo de la resolución de la pantalla, la parte blanca es aún mayor.

Un saludo y gracias.

---

Aquí dejo el pie.

```
    <!-- Pie -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4 class="mb-2 mt-3">Enlaces: </h4>
                    <dl> 
                        <dt>
                            <a href="http://www.iesjacaranda.es">Instituto.</a>
                        </dt>
                        <dt>
                            <a href="http://www.iesjacaranda-brenes.org/aulavirtual/">Aula virtual.</a>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4 class="mb-2 mt-3">Herramientas: </h4>
                    <dl> 
                        <dt>
                            <a href="https://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap.</a>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Es probable que sea un margin o un padding. Hay algún sitio donde se pueda ver a tiempo real la web?

Comment: Bootstrap, y la mayoría de frameworks responsive para web, se ajustan a la anchura de la pantalla, no a la altura. Si quieres que se ajuste, puedes intentar programar un pequeño código javascript para que te ajuste el tamaño del bloque central o del pie de la página.

Comment: Por lo general, en **HTML**  la altura de los contenedores se ajusta a su contenido, a no ser que especifiques lo contrario, como dándole al elemento una altura fija. En tu caso el `.container-fluid` que tienes entre la cabecera y el footer se está ajustando a su contenido, por lo que si el contenido no da para que la página ocupe el 100% de la altura del dispositivo, te va a quedar ese huevo abajo. Una posible solución sería esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/263028/41639

Comment: Hace falta ver el código de pie.php para saber cuál es  el problema exacto. Aunque me  voy a mojar y sugerir que el problema es el mismo que [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/267058/250) y que lo único que haría falta es aplicar la misma solución. De ese modo el pie se pegará a la parte baja de la página (que parece es lo que quieres).

Comment: He añado el pie para que se pueda ver. @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @Sparring ponle la clase fixed-bottom al footer. ¿Soluciona eso el problema?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Problema Espacio Bootstrap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/problema-espacio-bootstrap)

Comment: @JoséDelgado no es necesario usar javascript para esto, únicamente con CSS se puede lograr, siguiendo por ejemplo, los enlaces que citan los compañeros.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es agregar la clase **"fixed-bottom"** de Bootstrap 4 a tu footer

```
<footer class="fixed-bottom">
```

para que permanezca en la parte inferior de tu página.